# Getting Children Keywords from another Keyword

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, taxonomy, c#

I am trying to retrieve the Children Keywords of another Keyword from its URI with the following code:

```
if (kwdOrCatURI.StartsWith("tcm:"))
 {
     if (kwdOrCatURI.EndsWith("-1024"))
     {
         rootkeyword = factory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(kwdOrCatURI);
         taxonomychildren = GetKeywords(rootkeyword);
     }
 }
```

....

```
private static ArrayList GetKeywords(Keyword kwd)
{
    ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();
    if (kwd != null)
    {
        foreach (Keyword childkeyword in (IEnumerable)kwd.KeywordChildren)
        {
            arraylist.Add(childkeyword);
        }
    }
    return arraylist;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get the children, since the list is always empty. However if I "iterate" & "browse" over the category I am able to get to all its children...

Anyone has an example on how to retrieve the children of a Keyword from its URI without having to iterate over the entire category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, It seems it's been a while since I wrote code... it is quite simple, here the solution:

1. Get The keyword
2. From the Keyword, get its TaxonomyURI
3. Now using the API, get the keyword with its children:

   ```
   rootkeyword = factory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(kwdOrCatURI);
   //rootkeyword.TaxonomyUri
   rootkeyword = factory.GetTaxonomyKeywords(rootkeyword.TaxonomyUri, 
                                    new CompositeFilter(), kwdOrCatURI, new Keyword[]{});
   taxonomychildren = GetKeywords(rootkeyword);
   ```

Thank you Asier.

Comment: It is always a pleasure to help :)

Comment: Jamie, You should go ahead and mark your answer as the accepted answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet I have as my own example:

**To get your keyword**

```
using Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies;

TaxonomyFactory taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory();
Keyword keyWord = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeywords("yourcategorytcmid");
```

**Now you have your keyword**

You've access to:

```
keyWord.KeywordChildren
```

If you're going to loop this list it's best to check the object is of type

```
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies.Keyword
```